# Small in-text fractions

Tags: fractions

I'm writing things like 2/3 or 1/4 in my text and I'd like to make them appear as they do automatically in a processor like Word where they are slightly smaller and have the diagonal separation if that makes sense, instead of being placed on top of each other like it would appear in math mode.

Comment: try `nicefrac` package. welcome to tex.se.

Comment: If by any chance you're already using the Charter fonts via XCharter.sty, you could also use \textfrac{}{}

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you load the `xfrac` package and write `$\sfrac{1}{2}$` to achieve your formatting objective by hand.

If you want to fully automate the process of typesetting all inline-math fractions with the `\sfrac` macro, the following, LuaLaTeX-based solution may be of interest to you.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfrac}   % for \sfrac macro
\usepackage{luacode} % for "luacode" env.

%% Lua-side code
\begin{luacode}
function make_nice_fracs(s)
  return (s:gsub ( "(%d%d*)/(%d%d*)", "\\sfrac{%1}{%2}" ))
end
\end{luacode}
%% LaTeX-side code
\newcommand{\ActivateMakeNiceFracs}{\directlua{%
   luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer", 
      make_nice_fracs, "make_nice_fracs" )}}
\AtBeginDocument{\ActivateMakeNiceFracs}

\begin{document}
From $\sfrac{1}{22}$ to $\sfrac{33}{444}$. The quick brown dog\dots

From $1/22$ to $33/444$. The quick brown dog\dots

% Use whitespace before or after "/" suspends the Lua function
From $1 /22$ to $33/ 444$. The quick brown dog\dots
\end{document}
```